# Best way to avoid EAV model, but still allow for flexibility

Tags: java, sql, oracle, csv, groovy

I have a requirement to store CSV data in an Oracle database for later retrieval by dynamic query scripts. The data needs to be stored such that any column of the CSV data can be queried using SQL and performance is key (some CSV files are 100k+ lines).

The content of the CSV files (number of columns, headings, data types) is not known ahead of time and the system needs to be able to handle multiple file structures (which are added to a config file so the system knows how to read them, by people who don't know SQL).

My current solution, in order to avoid an EAV model, is to have my code create new tables every time a new CSV structure is added to the config file. I'm curious to know if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do. I'm not particularly fond of having my code create new tables in production at run-time.

The system is written in groovy, in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am inclined to go with your current solution, which is a separate table for each type.  Somehow, I'm most comfortable with storing data in well-defined tables with well-defined types.

An EAV (entity-attribute-value) solution is also viable.  With 100k rows of data, the EAV solution should perform pretty well, unless you have lots of tables.  One downside is the types of the columns.  Without a lot of extra work, you are pretty much limited to strings for all the values.

Oracle does offer another possibility, which is an XML solution.  This can give you the flexibility of dynamic column names along with the "simplicity" of not having to define a separate table for each one.  You can read more about it in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb01int.htm#ADXDB0100).

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to what you want to model.  If you need to handle adhoc queries against any of the columns in the CSV file, then I guess you need to model them all as Oracle columns.  If you need to only retrieve a whole line based on a particular key, then you could model as two columns: the key and the line.  If you need to model the individual columsn that such a thing would not be in first normal form.

When you create an EAV model, you are making a flexible system that allows for additional columns to be added/removed easily.  Oracle is already a flexible system that allows for additional columns to be added/removed easily.  They've just put more thought into locking, performance, scalability and tool support that your naive EAV model might have.

Overall, I think what you are probably doing is best.  It's not an easy problem and it's not exactly what Oracle was designed for so you might have issues with statistics and which indexes to create and so on.